# VACUUM takes very long and can not be cancelled

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, vacuum

I just issue this command to a table and its been an 2 hours but not finished: `vacuum verbose people_data`

I can not even cancel the process because I can not see the PID using this query:

```sql
SELECT pid,
       now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS duration,
       query,
       state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '5 minutes' 
  and state = 'idle'
order by duration desc;
```

The size of this table is only 16 GB.
The dead tuple counts only max 130 using (only 10 tables has dead tuple above 100) :

```
select n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, relname 
from pg_stat_all_tables 
where n_dead_tup > 100 
limit 20;
```

Now some people report me that they can not access the DB? Luckily this is development database, so it just halts the development process.

How can I cancel the vacuum without seeing the PID?

Comment: Well the vacuum process won't be `idle` if it's currently working, so your WHERE clause will never show it. Maybe it's not doing something and waiting for a lock. Change it to `WHERE state <> 'idle'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much time will a vacuum/autovacuum operation take?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44657/how-much-time-will-a-vacuum-autovacuum-operation-take)

Comment: Hi, nice insight. It does not answer my problem though. thanks @JohnK.N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VACUUM (VERBOSE)` will not block concurrent table access. You didn't use `VACUUM (FULL)`, did you?

The reason why you cannot see the autovacuum process is that it has `state = 'active'`. You can look into the view `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` to see if and how `VACUUM` is proceeding.

With a small table like that, the most likely explanation is that there is a concurrent open database transaction that is holding a high lock on the table. That could also explain why people report that they cannot access the database.

Comment: I didn't use `VACUUM FULL`, It's too dangerous because the HDD is less than 20% free. I just could not run any queries.  Luckily after a few hours of fiddling around, I cancel it accidentally by pressing the status text (somehow the text can be clicked.. how do i suppose to know that !) on my DBeaver GUI. It takes a while to cancel the ongoing `VACUUM`. thanks for the information. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I repeat: `VACUUM` does not block concurrent `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements.