# Postgres too Many References to Single Table is good or bad design

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, postgresql-performance, index-design

*I have a Postgres database schema for a web app that needs real-time data and hence a huge volume of select, update, insert queries. Data manipulation is done via Postgres stored procedure mostly*

**I have designed each table to have {created, updated, deleted}_by  user all points to user table Id. In total, I will have around ~100-150 such references.**

In the users table, I see 100+ lines in reference by

```
    TABLE "XXX" CONSTRAINT "XXXXX" FOREIGN KEY (updated_user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    TABLE "XXY" CONSTRAINT "XXY" FOREIGN KEY (created_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
...
...
...~150+
```

I wanted to know if it's a good design or not and are there any pros and cons of such a database design. Are there any pros and cons of it I would really love to hear from all?

Note my max data size/year will be < ~50GB/year

Note I have these indexes on `users` table

```
Indexes:
    "id_x" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ABC" btree (id, username, email)
    "XYZ" UNIQUE, btree (lower(email::text))
    "aaa" UNIQUE, btree (lower(username::text))
    "bbb" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "cccc" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the right design to enforce referential integrity.
The only index relevant for the FKs is the one on `(id)` - the PK index.
Your multicolumn index on `(id, username, email)` can still be useful if you join a lot and get [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) out of it. Else, you might drop it.

With ~ 150 FK references pointing to `users(id)` make sure the table and PK index are in good shape, i.e. use aggressive `autovacuum` settings to keep columns statistics and the visibility map up to date and bloat to a minimum. See:

- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/aggressive-autovacuum-on-postgresql/21649#21649)

Then again, since the `users` table is probably small, the impact is small accordingly.

Deleting a user needs to update ~ 150 columns in other tables. The big amount of necessary locks may block other operations temporarily or even lead to deadlocks. If you never change `users.id` anyway and can live with the occasionally broken reference, you might just drop all these FK constraints to save some complexity and performance.

Either way, be sure to `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN users` since your FK columns can obviously be NULL.

Aside: With a (stricter) `UNIQUE` index on `(lower(email))` in place, the additional `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on `(email)` seems redundant. Maybe you need the index on just `(email)`? Else, drop the constraint. Same for `username`.

Comment: Thank you so much @erwin-brandstetter for detailed answer. 
I was confused in between unique and unique constrain hence took chance and added both.
I want Abc@email.com , abc@email.com , abC@email.com all treated as same.

I believe     "aaa" UNIQUE, btree (lower(email::text)) should do.